# Can Ajax prevent GET parameters from being seen by the client?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

An API key has to be entered as a GET parameter and these are easily seen in the URL. I could try using ajax to call a page, which in turn uses `jQuery.get();` to fetch me the things I need, but is it possible for someone with more knowledge of a browser's inspector to find their way to the js variables of a page called via ajax?

If yes, then how do I protect the API key? The tutorials only explain how to use the API itself, as if the rest is common knowledge.

Comment: All data that is submitted from a client is easily seen (and manipulated) by the end user. The API key should be safe to hand over to the client. Keys should be revocable if compromised.

Comment: Why is it an issue if client can see the data they're sending?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anything in the browser space is essentially public.

So either you restrict the info available with the key to information you don't mid being seen, or you put an intermediary in the process - i.e. a server that does the look ups on the protected routes and passes back public info

Answer (score 0):

> Some notes on GET requests:
>
> - GET requests can be cached.
> - GET requests remain in the browser history.
> - GET requests can be bookmarked.
> - GET requests should never be used when dealing with sensitive data.
> - GET requests have length restrictions.
> - GET requests should be used only to retrieve data.

Source [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp)